# Unit Testing of Deferred Custom Actions in wix

Tags: c#, unit-testing, wix, custom-action, wix3.7

I have explored unit testing of immediate custom actions in wix with the Lux framework. I was hoping to know how can we use C# for unit testing of deferred custom actions written in wix.

```
<CustomAction Id="SetParamTestCustomActionSimple" Property="DBPORTNUMBER" Value="[DBPORTNUMBER]" Execute="immediate" />

<Property Id="DBPORTNUMBER" Secure="no" Value="1433"/>
 <!--Unit test in lux-->
        
<lux:UnitTest CustomAction="SetParamTestCustomActionSimple" Property="DBPORTNUMBER" Value="1433" Operator="equal" />
```

This is how I wrote a unit test in lux for an immediate custom action, but since Lux does not support deferred Custom Actions, how can I write unit test in C# for deferred a custom action?